# Extract content class with Xpath

Tags: php, xpath

I need to extract the content only of class ah_sec_product_price

```
<div class="col-12 order-1 order-sm-2 col-sm-8">
<div class="ah_sec_product_price_del">
<span class="discount_badge">٪۲۴</span> <del>۳۷,۰۰۰</del>
</div>
<div class="ah_sec_product_price">
                                                                    ۲۸,۴۰۶ تومان
</div>
</div>
```

I tried it like that, but I dont get any result.

```
$product_prices = $xpath_object->query('//div[contains(@class,"ah_sec_product_price")]');
```

I want to display only the content of the ah_sec_product_price class

With this command, the ah_sec_product_price_del class is displayed

output

```
٪۲۴ ۳۷,۰۰۰
```

Comment: [`//div[@class="ah_sec_product_price"]`](http://xpather.com/hfris0S2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your query:
Your query : '//div[contains(@class,"ah_sec_product_price")]'
Change it into : '//div[@class="ah_sec_product_price"]'.

After this change you will get your expected output.
Output : ۲۸,۴۰۶ تومان